# Microsoft.Data.SqlClient - Error pre-login handshake

Tags: c#, .net, sqlclient

I'm trying to use the Microsoft.Data.SqlClient but cannot get the connection to work. However when I use the System.Data.SqlClient everything is ok.

```
try
{
    using (var connection = new SC.SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();

        connection.State.ShouldBe(ConnectionState.Open);
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    throw;
}
```

The connection string is:

```
"server=[[**SERVER_NAME**]];Trusted_Connection=True;database=[[**DATABASE**]];min pool size=0;max pool size=100;Application Name=Data.Tests.DotNet;timeout=120"
```

The error that I am getting is:

```
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: HTTP Provider, error: 0 - )
```

Everything that I can find show some message after the 'error: 0 -'.

Can anyone help?

**UPDATE**

The company's environments are:

1. Dev / UAT - Ms Sql Server 2012 Enterprise (On-Prem)
2. Prod - Ms Sql Server 2016 Azure (Cloud)

Connection Strings:

1. Dev / UAT:

```
"server=[[**SERVER_NAME**]];Trusted_Connection=True;database=[[**DATABASE**]];min pool size=0;max pool size=100;Application Name=Data.Tests.DotNet;timeout=120"
```

2. Production:

```
"Server=tcp:[[**SERVER_NAME]],1433;database=[[**DATABASE**]];Persist Security Info=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Authentication='Active Directory Integrated';Application Name=Data.Tests.DotNet;"
```

Comment: The obvious question is, why can't you use System.Data.SqlClient?

Comment: Sure fair question: We have a environment where our Dev & Uat is a on prem ms sql server but our production is in Azure. We also have both .net 4.7.2 and core 3.1 applications. Further we have a "common" framework dll that has our database interaction classes. My test currently are showing that the System.Data.SqlClient are working connecting to Azure in .net 4.7.2 but the Core 3.1 is not.

Comment: System.Data.SqlClient does work in .Net Core 3.1. I know it for a fact. You may have a different issue there.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Adding "TrustServerCertificate=true" to the end of connection string may resolve the issue.

Comment: While it resolved my issue, doesn't this compromise the security of the connection?